# Bazaar: How to check if a local repo is up to date?

Tags: bash, bazaar

I want to refine a remote update script so it doesn't attempt to re-build the target if no changes were pulled by `bzr pull`.

Is there any easier way to do it rather than parsing the output from `bzr pull`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `bzr missing` command:

```
if ! bzr missing >/dev/null; then
    echo some revisions are missing
else
    echo we are in sync
fi
```

You can easily create dummy branches to test this:

```
mkdir dummy
cd dummy
bzr init trunk
cd trunk
date > date.txt
bzr add
bzr commit -m first
date >> date.txt
bzr commit -m second
bzr branch . -r1 ../behind
bzr branch . ../copy
cd ../copy
! bzr missing >/dev/null && echo behind || echo up to date
cd ../behind
! bzr missing >/dev/null && echo behind || echo up to date
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at the output of `bzr status -r branch:PATH_TO_REMOTE_BRANCH` to see if there are changes, before pulling.

Comment: Thank you. Whenever I'll see any actual changes on the remote end, I'll play around it, so I can use it in script to get a simple yes/no